# Export Active Directory users and their policies

Tags: active-directory, export, gpo

I would like to get in `.csv` (or any other readable format) all my AD users and the policies that they need to comply (What is their password policy and much much more).

`Get-ADUser` and `CSVDE` commands do not give me all the policies.

Basically I need sort of a merge between GPO per user...

Thanks,
Nir

Comment: please show us what you have tried

Comment: What do you mean? the commands?

Comment: get-aduser -filter * -properties * | export-csv c:\whatever.txt is an example, but i'm trying to get for example the type of authentication each user needs, his event logging properties and even which encryption he is allowed to use in BitLocker...